# Exposed ports become unresponsive after heavy load - Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, port

I run a Postgresql Docker container database in my server with the exposed port 5432. After a heavy load from users this container became unresponsive by the port.

```
docker run -d --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres --env POSTGRES_USER=user --env POSTGRES_DB=database -p 5432:5432 password
```

To resolve this I need to enter to the container, make a backup, restart the container and import the backup.

```
$ docker exec -it [id] sh
# pg_dump -U user dbname > dbexport.pgsql
# exit
$ docker cp [id]:/backup.pgsql ~/backup.pgsql
$ docker stop [id]
$ docker run -d --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres --env POSTGRES_USER=user --env POSTGRES_DB=database -p 5432:5432 password
$ docker exec -it [id] sh
# psql -U user database < backup.pgsql
# exit
```

And everything back to work until other heavy load.

Why this happens?

Comment: how you came to know that the docker had become unresponsive

Comment: I can't access to the database remotely, only accessing directly to the container. The application crashed because there is no connection to the database.